# Loop with if statements is not working properly in C

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to write a loop with some `if` statements in it, and the problem with the loop is that the user is going to enter a choice, either `H` or `S`. However, when the user enters `S`, the program goes straight to the `H` statement and goes through that and after it, it goes to the other statement.
Let me show you with the code:

```
int decision(struct CardDeck *deck) {
    char choice;
    printf("Value is %d\n", deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer);
    while (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer <= 21) 
    {
        if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer == 21) {
            printf("Blackjack!");
        }
        if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer > 21) {
            printf("Sorry, you lose");
        }
        if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer < 21) {
            printf("Would you like to hit or stand?\n");
            scanf("%c", &choice);
        }
        if (choice == 'H' || choice == 'h'); {
            printf("You wish to hit; here's your card\n");
            deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer += printCards(deck);
            printf("Your total is now %d\n", deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer);
        }
        if (choice == 'S' || choice == 's') {
            printf("You wished to stay\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So the output I'm getting when I enter `S` is:

```
Value is 18
Would you like to hit or stand?
S
You wish to hit; here's your card
Jack of Clubs
Your total is now 28
You wished to stay
Pess any key to continue . . .
```

And when I enter `H` the program runs like this:

```
Value is 16
Would you like to hit or stand?
h
You wish to hit; here's your card
4 of Clubs
Your total is now 20
Would you like to hit or stand?
You wish to hit; here's your card
2 of Spades
Your total is now 22
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So my problem here is that the program goes into the choice `H` and `h` even though I use `S` or `s`.
If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the problem, I would be grateful!

Comment: Try adding a space in scanf(): `scanf(" %c", &choice);`. This will ignore the trailing newline left in the input.

Comment: Also you have a while loop that continues so long as `deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer <= 21` and then you have an if test inside that where you test `if(deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer > 21)` this can never happen

Comment: For your own safety and sanity, change the format string in the `scanf()` call to `scanf(" %c", &choice)` — with a space before the `%c` so that the input skips trailing newlines and the like from previous inputs.  You should also test the return value from `scanf()` to make sure you actually read what you expected: `if (scanf(" %c", &choice) != 1) { …EOF or other problem; time to bail out… }`.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code. What happens if `deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer > 21`? And use a consistent coding style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the if statement for the h one.

Comment: Oups.... Well sometimes you dont see it with your own eyes haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See notes in comments.

```
int decision(struct CardDeck *deck) {
    char choice;
    printf("Value is %d\n", deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer);
    while (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer <= 21) 
    {
        // ------> NOTE you should clear choice in each iteration
        choice = 0;

        // ------> NOTE probably need to break out of while here
        if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer == 21) {
            printf("Blackjack!");
        }
        // ------> NOTE this will never execute
        // you should move this to the hit block
        if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer > 21) {
            printf("Sorry, you lose");
        }
        if (deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer < 21) {
            printf("Would you like to hit or stand?\n");
            scanf("%c", &choice);
        }
        // ------> NOTE you have a ';' after the closing parenthesis
        if (choice == 'H' || choice == 'h'); {
            printf("You wish to hit; here's your card\n");
            deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer += printCards(deck);
            printf("Your total is now %d\n", deck->ValueOfSecondPlayer);
        }
        if (choice == 'S' || choice == 's') {
            printf("You wished to stay\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```